# google places autocomplete api not working in android

Tags: android, google-places-api, typed-arrays

I am using Google Places Autocomplete API in my android application. But the app doesn't work . The logcat is filled with these warnings.  There is this warning regarding TypedArray which I think is creating the problem.Can anyone explain what may be the issue.The logcat content is given below.

```html
02-02 20:47:42.638  19323-19323/com.devastrix.user.sharearide I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
02-02 20:47:42.638  19323-19323/com.devastrix.user.sharearide W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 369: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
02-02 20:47:42.639  19323-19323/com.devastrix.user.sharearide D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-02 20:47:42.640  19323-19323/com.devastrix.user.sharearide I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
02-02 20:47:42.640  19323-19323/com.devastrix.user.sharearide W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 391: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
02-02 20:47:42.641  19323-19323/com.devastrix.user.sharearide D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-02 20:47:42.852  19323-19323/com.devastrix.user.sharearide D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 248K, 5% free 10618K/11120K, paused 12ms, total 13ms
02-02 20:47:42.873  19323-19323/com.devastrix.user.sharearide I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 21.279MB for 9216016-byte allocation
02-02 20:47:43.066  19323-19323/com.devastrix.user.sharearide I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018_msm8610_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
    Build Date: 03/07/14 Fri
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.1
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018 + f2fd134 +  NOTHING
02-02 20:47:43.119  19323-19323/com.devastrix.user.sharearide D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-02 20:47:58.486  19323-19323/com.devastrix.user.sharearide W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Problem solved. by the way thanks for ur response...